# jQuery/Javascript : How to prepend elements without going back to the top of last prepended element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

Whenever I click `prepend`, after all elements are prepended, the view of the chat area switches to the top of the chat area or the last prepended element. This is different from `append`, whereby after all elements are appended, the view of the chat area **does not** switch to the end of the chat area or last appended element but still stays at its previous position.

How do I make the `prepend` function act in the same way as `append` in the sense that the view of the chat area **does not** change similar to FB's load previous message function?

Here is a sample code that illustrates what I mean.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<style type="text/css">
    .chatbox{
        border:1px solid #2a6496;
        height: 600px;
        margin-top:50px;
    }
    .chatbox div{
        height: 100%;
    }
    .rightP{
        border-left: 1px solid #2a6496;
    }
    .rightP .contents{
        border-bottom: 1px solid #2a6496;
        height: 70%;
    }
    .rightP .send{
        padding : 5% 5% 5% 5%;
        height: 30%;
    }

    #response{
        height: 200px;
        overflow-y: scroll;
        overflow-wrap: break-word;
    }

</style>
<script>
    function appendMessage()
    {
        var data = 'hello';
        var message = document.createElement('p');
        message.innerHTML = data;
        console.log(message.innerHTML);
        $('#response').append(message);
        $('#response').append($('.load'));
    }
    function prependMessage()
    {
        for(var $i = 0;$i<10;$i++)
        {
            var data = 'hello'+$i;
            var message = document.createElement('p');
            message.innerHTML = data;
            console.log(message.innerHTML);
            $('#response').prepend(message);
            $('#response').prepend($('.load2'));
        }
    }
</script>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="chatbox">
        <div class="col-sm-8 rightP">
            <div class="row contents">
                <div class="row msg">
                    <div id="response" class="msg form-group">
                        <a onclick="return appendMessage()" class="load btn btn-default">Append</a>
                        <a onclick="return prependMessage()" class="load2 btn btn-default">Prepend</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your `if(messages.length<10)` is in the wrong place (its part of the ajax parameters).

Comment: @Heanz thanks mate. Was editing in haste. Corrected~

Answer (score 0):

In HTML there should be `return` in your onlick:

```
<a onclick="return loadMessage();" class="load btn btn-default">Load More Msg</a>
```

In JS you need to add `return false` to your function `loadMessage`.

```
var loadMessage = function(){
    var firstMessage = $messagesWrapper.find('> p:nth-child(2)');
    $.ajax({
        ....
        if(messages.length<10){
                   $('.load').hide();//hide the load button if remaining messages to load is <10
                }
        success: function(messages){
            $.each(messages, function() {
               prependMessage(this);
           });
       },
       ....
   });

   return false;
};
```

Comment: erm, unfortunately it didn't do anything. I have added 1 more pic below the 2nd 1 to explain my question further and also edited my JS code to display the full codes. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div id="response" class="msg form-group">
     <a onclick="loadMessage(); return false;" class="load btn btn-default">Load More Msg</a>
</div>
```

If this doesn't work, try another way:

```
var loadMessage = function(){
    e.preventDefault(); // preventing any scroll action
    var firstMessage = $messagesWrapper.find('> p:nth-child(2)');
    (...)
```

And

```
var prependMessage = function(data){
     e.preventDefault(); // preventing any scroll action
     var message = document.createElement('p');
     (...)
```

If this doesn't work please provide the whole code so we can reproduce.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. I have edited my question and given a whole new sample code to reproduce the effect. Do check it out. Thanks!